# Android app consisting of Sound Effects - how to copy files?

Tags: android

I wanted to create an app that consists mostly of sound effects - imagine a theme of sound effects.

The UI of the app would reflect the general theme and consist of buttons like "**Copy sounds to device**" and "**Delete copied sounds from device**"

Once the app has copied the sounds to the device, I would like to make the `MediaScanner` aware of the new files.

**Problem:** With the limits on the SDcard, how is it possible for a non-system app to copy the files to the sdcard or even delete them ?

Comment: `app that consists mostly of sound effects` means? where the sounds are kept?

Comment: `With the limits on the SDcard` Set the permissions for writing files.

Comment: I'll try requesting permission to write to the SDcard and having the mediascanner scan that folder. My pessimistic side of my brain has doubts that it'll successfully expose the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst working on this feature, I discovered :

1)`getExternalStorageDirectory()` is useless on new versions of Android

2) the Media Scanner is unable to access the folder supplied by `getExternalFilesDir()`

**Solution**

Copy files to a public folder obtained with `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)